# Loop For Webscraping In Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I need to scrape all the products in this page: [website](https://www.asos.com/women/new-in/new-in-clothing/cat/?cid=2623&nlid=ww%7Cnew%20in%7Cnew%20products%7Cclothing)

**So I need to click on each photo then scrape the data inside them.**

**I managed to write the script for scraping the data inside.**

I had to extract the name, price, description,...

Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which

class AsoswomennewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'asoswomennew'
    allowed_domains = ['www.asos.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.asos.com/monki/monki-lisa-cropped-vest-top-with-ruched-side-in-black/prd/23590636?colourwayid=60495910&cid=2623']


def __init__(self):
    chrome_option = Options()
    chrome_option.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options = chrome_option)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    driver.get('https://www.asos.com/monki/monki-lisa-cropped-vest-top-with-ruched-side-in-black/prd/23590636?colourwayid=60495910&cid=2623')


def parse(self, response):

           yield{
           'name':response.xpath("//div[@class='product-hero']/h1/text()").get(),
           'price':response.css('//*[contains(@class, "current-price")]').get(),
           'description':response.xpath("//div[@class='product-description']/ul/li/span/text()").getall(),
           'about_me':response.xpath("//div[@class='about-me']/p/text()").getall(),
           'brand_description':response.xpath("//div[@class='brand-description']/p/text()").getall()
        }
```

Now I need to loop through each of the pictures then do the script above.

[pictures to loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvCyZ.jpg)

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

P.S my **start_url** will need to change to this one 'https://www.asos.com/women/new-in/new-in-clothing/cat/?cid=2623&nlid=ww|new+in|new+products|clothing'

As this is the main(home) webpage and then I will need to have a callback url for each items.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the products are wrapped in an `article` tag.

And each `article` tag has an `a` tag which basically consists of the the link to that product.

You can grab the `a` tag in each `article` tag in the home page and store them in a `list`. Let's say the `list` name is `products_list`.

After `driver.get()` something like this:

```
products_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('article a')
```

Then extract the `href` value of every `a` tag from the list and store them in another `list` named `products_links`

```
products_links = []
for each in products_list:
    products_links.append(each.get_attribute('href'))
```

Now, all you have to do is, loop through the `products_links` and open each one, parse the data you need. Just like how you did for a single product